# Entropy of large sample $X$ and small sample $Y$ comparison

Tags: inference, entropy, small-sample, information-theory, paired-data

- Distribution $X$ of a real continuous random variable is unimodal and slightly non-normal with $1,000$ observations.
- Distribution $Y$ has the same characteristics (not perfectly identical in moments though), but only has $500$ observations.

If I calculate the differential entropies of $X$ and $Y$, can I still make the regular inference comparison about which of the two distributions is less predictable (higher entropy), even though $X$ is a large sample dataset, and $Y$ is a low sample dataset?